# Visual Basic, declare datatype dynamically

Tags: xml, vb.net, dynamic, types

I need to declare a datatype dynamically depending on the result of a string variable. For example, if the string is `"TextBox"` I need to create an object `Me.var = New System.Windows.Forms.TextBox()`. The last one `"...TextBox()"` should be variable depending on what's in the string variable. I heard a dynamic declaration is possible in Java, maybe also in VB?

Answer (score 1):

```
Activator.CreateInstance()
```

can create an instance of a given Type object.  Look into creating a Type from your string.  Keep in mind that the string used will need be very specific; "Textbox" won't be enough.  But you could likely create a lookup between whatever your strings are and the actual type strings needed

Answer (score 0):

You can declare it as `Object`, and initialize it as the type you want.

```
Dim variable As Object
If condition Then
    variable = New System.Windows.Forms.TextBox()
Else
    variable = New Hashtable()
End If
```

Comment: Ok thank you :) I tried not to use If-Clauses but that it seems there's no way without them^^   Thanks! ;)